# Did moon gravitational force pulled metals and minerals higer?

Tags: gravity, planets, moon

Robert J. Sawyer's novel [Illegal Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_Alien_(Sawyer_novel)) states:

> A civilization living on a planet without a moon has much bigger
>   trouble mining raw resources because moon's gravitational pull pulled
>   materials higher from planet's crust. This leaves Earth with a big
>   advantage in natural resources availability.

Is this idea grounded in truth, or just a story convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misrepresenting the book somewhat.

For various reasons the easily mined mineral deposits on Earth tend to be associated with the boundaries of tectonic plates. The claim made in the book by the Tosok called Hask is that the Moon is partially or wholly (it isn't clear exactly what Hask means) responsible for the Earth's tectonic activity and therefore indirectly for the availability of easily mined minerals.

However plate tectonics is driven by convection currents in the mantle and the Moon has little or no influence on this. The claim made in the book is therefore not founded on fact.

Answer (score 0):

I think he got the reason wrong, the Earth's gravity will still cause the prevailing effect to be that denser objects sink to the center.

It is believed in the leading theory that a large planetoid named Theia collided with the Earth during the formation of the moon. This collision would have redistributed some of the heavier elements from inside the planet back to the surface.